# How to declare environment variable types with flow js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

Environment variables accessed from `process.env` are considered undefined when running `flow` since the parser has no idea what is included inside of them.

How do I tell the parser that the `env` object exists and what keys does it include?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1192

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents of environment variables is like any other input given at runtime: it cannot be known statically. Therefore Flow must be conservative and force you to validate it with runtime checks. Here are two examples of runtime checks that work (copied from https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1192#issuecomment-299140919)

```
// throw
if (!process.env.FOO) throw new Error('FOO missing');
const foo = process.env.FOO;

// fall back
const bar = process.env.BAR || 'bar';

(foo: string); // ok!
(bar: string); // ok!
```